# Define domain $X,$ predicate $A(X)$ and $B(X)$

Tags: logic, quantifiers, predicate-logic

I'm having trouble creating a domain $X$ and the predicates $A(X)$ and $B(X)$ to for this set of sentences to be evaluated to be true or false.

$(T)\quad \forall x \in X, (A(x) \rightarrow B(x))$

$(F)\quad \exists x \in X (A(x) \land B(x))$

---

I've tried letting X be the set of all natural numbers, A(x): "x is even", B(x): "x is odd" as it worked in past questions. However, I'm stumped on this one. I also want to know if I can use a more generic domain and predicate rather than being limited to numbers? If so, how? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The first sentence is confusing. You want interpretations for $A$ and $B$ such that the statements are true or false? That's always gonna happen.

Comment: Does the T before the first statement means that you want A, B and X such that the statement is true?

Comment: Sorry! Let me try to reword it. I need to define the domain X and predicates A(x), B(x) so that the first sentence is True and the second sentence is False.

Comment: What is meant by domain? Can X be any set? If so the empty set with any A and B seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $A(x):$ "x is $\dfrac 13$".

Define $B(x):$ "x is an integer."

And let the domain be the set of integers. Then the first sentence is true, but the second sentence is false. The first sentence is true vacuously, because $\frac 13 \notin \mathbb  Z$, and an implication is true whenever the antecedent is false. The second is false, since $\lnot \exists x \in \mathbb Z$ such that $x = \frac 13$, and a conjunction is true if and only if both conjuncts are true.

Comment: ... But the second sentence is **true** in your setting. There is an $x \in \mathbb Z$, say $x = 2$, which is an integer and natural.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Is there a way I can make it even more generic than that? My professor keeps telling me that we should try to use the largest possible domain.

Comment: Let $A(x) = "x = \frac 12"$, this will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any suggestions on how to tackle these type of problems where I need to define my own domain and predicate?